while working on vs code using django framework faced error
used python manage.py instead got this error.
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\
i was expecting to get a file db.sqlt.3 file and a link to a host site. What to do and how to fix this

The error message suggests that there is something wrong in your code or configuration. Unfortunately you have not provided the details of either that would allow us to help you.
